# TypeError: undefined is not a function [React Native]

Tags: react-native

I need help with this, I'm stuck

This is my custom component DataSlideInput.js
and the debugger gives me TypeError: undefined is not a function in every call to any custom component. Like  or

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Colors} from './colors.js';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import {CheckBox, Icon} from '@rneui/themed';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/core';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

import {setUsername, setPassword, setRememberMe} from '../redux/loginSlice';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

const DataSlideInput = props => {
  const userName = useSelector(state => state.login.userName);
  const password = useSelector(state => state.login.password);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <TextInput
      theme={{roundness: 30}}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      placeholderTextColor={Colors.placeholderColor}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      mode="outlined"
      label={props.label}
      secureTextEntry={props.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
      outlineColor={Colors.secondary}
      activeOutlineColor={Colors.secondary}
      style={styles.dataSlideInput}
      value={props.label == 'Email' ? userName : password}
      onChangeText={value => {
        if (props.label == 'Email') {
          dispatch(setUsername(value));
        }
        if (props.label == 'Password') {
          dispatch(setPassword(value));
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

const RememberMe = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const rememberMe = useSelector(state => state.login.rememberMe);

  return (
    <View style={styles.rememberMe}>
      <CheckBox
        checkedIcon={
          <Icon
            name="radio-button-checked"
            type="material"
            color={Colors.secondary}
            size={25}
            iconStyle={{marginRight: 10}}
          />
        }
        uncheckedIcon={
          <Icon
            name="radio-button-unchecked"
            type="material"
            color={Colors.secondary}
            size={25}
            iconStyle={{marginRight: 10}}
          />
        }
        checked={rememberMe}
        onPress={() => {
          dispatch(setRememberMe(!rememberMe));
        }}
      />
      <Text style={styles.rememberMeText}>Recordarme en este dispositivo</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const LogInButton = () => {
  const userName = useSelector(state => state.login.userName);
  const password = useSelector(state => state.login.password);
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (userName != '' && password != '') {
      navigation.navigate('MapaOnline');
    } else {
      if (userName == '' && password == '')
        Toast.show('Por favor, complete E-mail y Contraseña', Toast.SHORT);
      else {
        if (userName == '')
          Toast.show(
            'El casillero de E-mail no puede quedar vacio',
            Toast.SHORT,
          );
        if (password == '')
          Toast.show('La contraseña no puede ser vacia', Toast.SHORT);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.dataSlideLogInButton}
      onPress={() => handleSubmit()}>
      <Text style={styles.dataSlideLogInButtonText}>Entrar</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const ConfigButton = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Config')}
      style={styles.dataSlideConfig}>
      <Text style={styles.dataSlideConfigText}>Ir a configuración</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dataSlideInput: {
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    width: '80%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    height: 45,
  },
  rememberMe: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '80%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    height: 60,
  },
  rememberMeText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginLeft: -20,
    marginBottom: 7,
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
  },
  dataSlideLogInButton: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: Colors.secondary,
    backgroundColor: Colors.secondary,
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: '80%',
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 35,
  },
  dataSlideLogInButtonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: Colors.primary,
  },
  dataSlideConfig: {
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  dataSlideConfigText: {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 17,
    color: Colors.headerColor,
  },
});

export {DataSlideInput, RememberMe, LogInButton, ConfigButton};
```

And I'm trying to put it here. This was working before, but this morning stop...

```
   /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * Generated with the TypeScript template
 * https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript
 *
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {Colors} from '../component/colors';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

import {createTable, getDataFromDB} from '../Database/databaseConfig';
import {
  DataSlideInput,
  RememberMe,
  LogInButton,
  ConfigButton,
} from '../component/DataSlideInput';

//configuration -> loading
// related items -> elements or files

const currentRow = ''; //activities detailedInformation relatedItems editedElements connectedElements

const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    createTable();
    getDataFromDB(dispatch);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.backgroundStyle}>
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('../component/icons/background.jpg')}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>ISMobile</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.companyLogo}
          source={require('../component/icons/logo.png')}
        />

        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
          <Animatable.View animation="fadeInUp" style={styles.dataSlide}>
            <Text style={styles.dataSlideHeader}>
              Ingresá tus datos para continuar.
            </Text>

            <DataSlideInput
              placeholder="Email"
              label="Email"
              secureTextEntry={false}
            />

            <DataSlideInput
              placeholder="Password"
              label="Password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />

            <RememberMe />

            {/* Clicking LogIn button redirects to mapaOnline  */}
            <LogInButton />

            {/* Clicking Config button redirects to config */}
            <ConfigButton />
          </Animatable.View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  headerText: {
    color: Colors.primary,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginTop: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  backgroundStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: Colors.secondary,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  companyLogo: {
    marginTop: 60,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
  dataSlide: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 30,
    width: '100%',
    height: '70%',
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
  },
  dataSlideHeader: {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },
  dataSlideConfig: {
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  dataSlideConfigText: {
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif-condensed',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontSize: 17,
    color: Colors.headerColor,
  },
});

export default Login;

{
  /*                 <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate(currentRow)}
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 10,
                        alignSelf: "center",
                    }}>
                    <Text style={{
                        fontFamily: "sans-serif-condensed",
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        fontSize: 17,
                        color: Colors.headerColor
                    }}>debug</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity> */
}
```

[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pBC4.png)

If anyone knows how to fix it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What did you change this morning?

Comment: @Abe nothing... just debug in a mobile insted the emulator

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of react-redux.

I installed a previous version and it solved the problem

> npm install react-redux@7.0.2